# postgres force json datatype

Tags: json, postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

When working with JSON datatype, is there a way to ensure the input JSON must have elements. I don't mean primary, I want the JSON that gets inserted to at least have the id and name element, it can have more but at the minimum the id and name must be there.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function checks what you want:

```
create or replace function json_has_id_and_name(val json)
returns boolean language sql as $$
    select coalesce(
        (
            select array['id', 'name'] <@ array_agg(key)
            from json_object_keys(val) key
        ),
        false)
$$;


select json_has_id_and_name('{"id":1, "name":"abc"}'), json_has_id_and_name('{"id":1}');

 json_has_id_and_name | json_has_id_and_name 
----------------------+----------------------
 t                    | f
(1 row)
```

You can use it in a check constraint, e.g.:

```
create table my_table (
    id int primary key,
    jdata json check (json_has_id_and_name(jdata))
);

insert into my_table values (1, '{"id":1}');

ERROR:  new row for relation "my_table" violates check constraint "my_table_jdata_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, {"id":1}).
```

Comment: will this work when somebody update as well?  sorry i have not tried, i will in a little when i get to my station.